# Adding Equal Earth Projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj, qgis-3

There is a new accurate projection for world maps ► [Equal Earth](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/does-this-map-tell-the-truth-or-just-tell-a-smaller-lie).

I know its [proj4](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/eqearth.html#cmdoption-arg-lon-0) but I can't add it in QGIS (see below). Does it need some kind of QGIS update?

[image]

Comment: Warning: Don't  be fooled by terminology or marketing. All map projections distort in some way and all projections are accurate in some way. This "new" projection is (just) another *equal-area* projection. If you're unsure about this, research *map projections*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Twitter Tom Patterson posted this tweet and it works:

The latest [#QGIS](https://twitter.com/hashtag/QGIS?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) 3.4.0 supports [#EqualEarthProjection](https://twitter.com/hashtag/EqualEarthProjection?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) in two steps:
(1) In Settings -> Custom Projections… create a custom definition with “+proj=eqearth +datum=WGS84 +wktext”
(2) Select the definition in Project -> Properties… -> CRS -> under “User Defined Coordinate System” [pic.twitter.com/InWzw3IEiV](https://t.co/InWzw3IEiV)— Tom Patterson (@MtnMapper) [October 30, 2018](https://twitter.com/MtnMapper/status/1057303396196249600?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Answer (score 9):

This projection has been added to the `5.2.0.` version of PROJ.4.

If you go in QGIS to Help>>About, you'll see that it uses an earlier version of PROJ.4

If you want this projection now, you'll have to wait for the newer version of QGIS (Which would use this updated Proj.4 version), or you can compile QGIS yourself.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 3.4 uses PROJ 5.2.0, but it still says +proj=eqearth is invalid. It works in the terminal however, I am able to convert coordinates in Equal Earth projection to WGS84.

[image]