# Different prime meridian in equal earth projection with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to use the equal earth projection with a prime meridian other than Greenwich (0°) in QGIS?

[Adding Equal Earth Projection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295203/adding-equal-earth-projection-in-qgis) shows how to use the equal earth projection with QGIS, but the prime meridian is "fixed" at 0° (Greenwich)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to set any central meridian using +lon_0 parameter:
“+proj=eqearth +lon_0=-90 +datum=WGS84 +wktext”