# Defining Equal Earth Projection in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am trying to define a custom CRS based on Equal Earth Projection (As described [here](https://twitter.com/MtnMapper/status/1057303396196249600)) in QGIS (Settings >> Custom Projections >>  **+** [`Add new CRS`] >> Entering Proj String [`+proj=eqearth +datum=WGS84 +wktext`] >> OK).
The [validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFAzW.png) of the Proj String goes fine; however, after pressing OK it gives the following error message.

```
Cannot save' * Generated CRS (+proj=aeqd +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 + datum=WGS84 + units= m + no_defs)' 
— this Proj string definition is identical to ESRI:54032.
Try changing the CRS definition to a WKTformat instead.
```

[image: Error Message when trying to define Equal Earth Projection]

I thought that probably ESRI:54032 and Equal Earth maybe the same thing. But when I change my map projection to ESRI:5432, it does not looks like [Equal Earth Projections](https://proj.org/operations/projections/eqearth.html).

Are the Equal Earth and ESRI:54032 the same?
If not, how can I define the Equal Earth projection in QGIS?

I am using QGIS 3.12 (64 bit) on Windows 10. Detailed specification about QGIS and related libraries is here.

[image: Detailed specification about QGIS]

A similar question ([Adding Equal Earth Projection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295203)) already exists but neither the question nor the answers address the problem I have described.

Comment: In the steps description says that you entered the `+proj=eqearth +datum=WGS84 +wktext` PROJ string, but in the screenshot there is another string (about an azimuthal equidistant projection). Is QGIS changing the input string?

Comment: Well! I didn't notice it before. However, I entered the same PROJ string as I mentioned here (Please see the [validation step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFAzW.png)). QGIS changes the text itself when I press OK as you are seeing in the screenshot after pressing OK.

Comment: I have not a QGIS 3.12 install to test it, but in QGIS 3.10 the message says that the CRS definition is the same as `EPSG:8857` CRS (true). If you think that everyone with QGIS 3.12 will be able to reproduce that _"change of string"_, please report it as a bug.

Comment: Try EPSG:8857 it is already defined in QGIS.

Comment: I have the same problem with the projection definition and text change

Comment: I have the same probklem in version 3.10.4
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2cdX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2cdX.png) Usually I could make several CRSs with the same basic parameters just different transformation parameters and it was OK.